# Update Filters name which are present In Product Listing Page

Tags: magento-1.9, filter

I have enabled filters on Product Listing Page. I want to Update the Filters name.

For e.g - From Category To Sub Category, Price to Price Range.

[image: Filters With Name]

Below is code from catalog/navigation/left.phtml file.

```
<?php
if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) {
    return;
}
?>

<?php
$categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories();
$count = is_array($categories)?count($categories):$categories->count();
?>

<?php if ($count): ?>
    <div class="filters">
        <dl class="filters_facet-list">
            <dd>
                <ol class="filters_option-list">
                    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
                        <?php if ($category->getIsActive()): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category); ?>" <?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?>class="current"<?php endif; ?>>
                                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()); ?>
                                    <span class="count"><?php echo $category->getProductCount(); ?></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Price and Size filter you can do this by change the title of attribute in Catalog -> Attributes -> Attribute Sets -> attribute -> Attribute Information -> Manage Label/Option

    and for category name change title you can do in file

     catalog/navigation/left.phtml

It seems you have edit your catalog/navigation/left.phtml so you can customize as per default theme

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml
```

Comment: I have tried, but not changed from Category to SubCategory. In my case, That Filters are coming from /template/catalog/layer/view.phtml